# Two queries. Min(frd) from the second query doesn't appear in the list of values returned in the first query. Why would this be?

Tags: sql, count, min

Why does the min(frd) of 1882-02-02 not appear in the top query where I'm displaying counts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhere in the 1000 rows.  If you want the data in order, then you need an `order by`.  Add:

```
order by frd
```

to your aggregation query.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes complete sense.